# JavaScript seInterval/clearInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a small problem.
The code is like this:

```
var myModule = (function() {
var _fun = function() {
  console.log('dummy content');
};

var _init = function() {
  _fun();
};

return {
  init: _init,
}

})();

setInterval(myModule.init, 1000);
```

Is there any option to `clearInterval()` right after `setInterval()` and then start it once again ?
I would like to achieve something like this because each time I `seInterval()` I should clear it but unfortunately I don't know how to do this :/

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You should use the setTimeout method. This will only call the callback once.

Comment: @Wazner but I want to repeat this function but also I need to clear this interval right after that and do this once again and so on'

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Why do you want to clear the interval.

Comment: The more active intervals you have, the more RAM and CPU time your web page uses, so it is a good practice to clear interval if you don't need it anymore
but in this case I would like to setinterval, clear it and do this continuously

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign setInterval return value to a variable and then use clearInterval on it, eg:

```
var myVar = setInterval(myModule.init, 1000);
clearInterval(myVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myModule = (function() {
var _fun = function() {
  console.log('dummy content');
};

var _init = function() {
  _fun();
};

return {
  init: _init,
}

})();

var interval = setInterval(myModule.init, 1000); // creates interval
clearInterval(interval); // clears the interval created above
```

Comment: ok, but it will run function once, then clear interval and do nothing. The thing I would like to achieve is to run function, clear interval each time after function run and the once again do this

Comment: you can put `clearInterval(interval)` inside the function.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: you can always clear it inside the function by calling `clearInterval`

Answer (score 0):

When you set your interval keep a reference to it:

```
intervalObj = setInterval(yourCallbackFuction, INTERVAL_TIME);
```

Then clearing it:

```
 clearInterval(intervalObj);
```